# How to tailor the view used when displaying the drop-down perspective

Tags: android, android-spinner

Guys sorry if I have offended someone by asking such a noob question, as I see someone have "Marked Down" Question for being inappropriate. I have just started learning Android myself and this forum is a real lifesaver. 
I'm trying to configure the adapter of Spinner in goal to tailor the view used when displaying the drop-down perspective.
I need to delete the radio-button from my listview .... For more understanding my goal , please see this picture in this link :

http://im31.gulfup.com/74Hl1.jpg

How do I do that? I googled a lot, but either I used the wrong keywords or there are no simple solutions on the internet. I hope somebody here can help me.

Best regards and thanks in advance, Fadel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "Unclear what you're asking". The image link that is intended to explain things is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look instead of using a spinner you can opt for drop down listview.

```
http://www.androidhive.info/category/list-view/
```

There are many more good Android beginner tutorials available there.